# Can a minimal separator of a diameter 2 interval graph be large?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm getting used to chordal graphs (and some subclasses of chordal graphs). As we know, the concept of a [*minimal separator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph#Minimal_separators) is central to chordal graphs. So recall a set $S \subseteq V(G)$ disconnects $a$ from $b$ if every path of $G$ between $a$ and $b$ contains a vertex from $S$. A non-empty set $S \subseteq V(G)$ is a minimal separator of $G$ if there exists $a$ and $b$ such that $S$ disconnects $a$ from $b$ in $G$, and no proper subset of $S$ disconnects $a$ from $b$ in $G$. A well-known characterization is that chordal graphs are exactly the graphs where each minimal separator is a clique.

A widely studied subclass of chordal graphs is given by [interval graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). These graphs seem to have many nice properties, for instance, such graphs always contain a dominating path.

Suppose the diameter of an interval graph $G$ is small, say $\text{diam}(G) = 2$. Such a graph will have exactly one minimal separator $S$ (otherwise you'd get larger diameter). How large can $S$ be? Surely $|S|=2$, but can it be even larger? It feels like if I try to make $S$ a triangle, I end up with an asteroidal triple (interval graphs can't have such triples), or make $\text{diam}(G) \geq 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $G=K_n-e$, the complete graph on $n$ vertices minus one edge $e=[u,v]$.
This graph $G$ is an interval graph, and its only (and of course minimal) separator consists of $n-2$ vertices that separate $u$ from $v$.

Comment: Or, for example, take a $K_3$, and add 3 vertices you connect to each vertex in the $K_3$. This generalizes too.

Comment: @Gideon that does not make a diameter-2 graph